# Не могу использовать python библиотеки

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, opencv, pip

Python 3.9 успешно у меня установлен. Некоторые библиотеки как numpy , pandas , opencv и прочие ничего не выводят при запуске программы а сразу же завершаются. Тоже самое не происходит со многими другими библиотеками. Что это значит? Стоит ли мне переустанавливать python

Машина : windows 10 , 32 bit

Comment: При запуске какой программы библиотеки ничего не выводят?

Comment: Что значит "при запуске программ библиотеки ЗАВЕРШАЮТСЯ. Поясните, что вы имеете ввиду. Я понимаю, когда завершается программа, но когда завершается библиотека?